# Jquery find and append performance issue when building big hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, find, append

I need to recursively read a hierarchic JSON object and build the HTML the same way as children objects will have to be inserted inside parents object.

Example:
    `<div class="level0">`
      `<div class="children1 level1">`
        `<div class="children1 level2">`
          .... N children
        `</div>`
          ... N Children
      `</div>`
    `</div>`
    ... N Parents

Now, I'm building this with the following code:

```
function buildDivHtml(); // This generates all the parent/children code at that particular moment, meaning one by one.
object.find('selector of the row where the append goes').append('html from above function');
```

This causes browser to freeze. Is there a way to do this that works flawlessly without browser freezing?

Comment: are you appending in loop ?

Comment: yes I am appending on each loop cause it is hierarchic data